# jquery highlight effect with hide mode not working on IE

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, highlight, effect

I have a div to show a message, I want the message to appear for a few seconds and then just fade until it disappears.

I just define a normal div and hide it when the page loads with $('#mydiv').hide();

I have a button to show the div with the desired effect, for this, I'm using:

```
  $('#myDiv').fadeIn('fast').effect("highlight", { color: "green", mode:"hide" }, 5000);
```

This works perfectly on Firefox and Chrome, but on IE (tried it on 6, 7 and 8) it works only the first time, after that it won't show the message.

If there's no way to achieve this in IE, I would like to know how can I do a fadeOut or something like that AFTER the highlight has ended.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this [jQuery ticket](http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/4845) is related to your problem.

The workaround I found is to add

```
$('#myDiv').removeAttr('style');
```

before

```
$('#myDiv').fadeIn('fast')
           .effect("highlight", { color: "green", mode:"hide" }, 5000);
```

to clear the IE filter issue.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking I don't chain effects. You probably want to use a callback instead:

```
$('#myDiv').fadeIn('fast', function() {
  $(this).effect("highlight", { color: "green", mode:"hide" }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: The fadeIn was working alright using it chained, about the callback, that's exactly what I was looking for, I didn't know that I could add a callback as the fourth argument on the effect method, that did the trick (instead of using mode:"hide" I use the hide() method in a callback. Thanks!

Comment: my effects were happening at the same time due to chaining them and switching to callback fixed it.